# Should I instantiate a submodule in large angular apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I am building a large angular app comprised of various modules

```
- app
  -- member
    --- newMember
    --- memberDashboard
  -- linguistics
  -- etc
     --- etc etc
```

In the html I am instantiating individual modules, because I believe there to be a performance improvement over bootstrapping the entire `app`.

```
<div ng-app="linguistics">
    <div ui-view autoscroll="true"></div>
</div>
```

However, this means that I have to repeat myself in module configuration. i.e.:

```
angular.module('linguistics', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'googlechart',
    'babelServices',
    'babelFilters'
]).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}).config(function($provide) {
    return $provide.decorator('$uiViewScroll', function($delegate, $window) {
        return function(uiViewElement) {
            //eventually do something more intelligent with the uiViewElement
            return $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        };
    });
});
```

html5Mode, scrollTo etc will be repeated across modules. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add a configuration module, that will handle the grunt work of setting up html5Mode, scrollTo etc.

```
angular.module('configuration', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($locationProvider, $provide) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    // For angular 1.3
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: /* true/false */
    });

    $provide.decorator('$uiViewScroll', function ($delegate, $window) {
      return function (uiViewElement) {
        return $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
    });
  });
```

And then in your subsequent modules:

```
angular.module('linguistics', ['configuration']);
```

Comment: Cool idea. Thanks! I haven't accepted your answer yet because I'm holding out for any information on the relative performance of loading the top level module compared to one of the constituent modules.